# Is it possible to change multiple png images to 'harmonise' their colour scheme?

Tags: css

I have a bunch of company logos which are all png images, they're all different colours.

What I'm looking to do is apply the same css code to all images to harmonise their colours. E.g. if you go to the Nextjs website and scroll down, they have a bunch of company logos which are all in greyscale. I'm looking to build something similar but with a slightly bluer tone.

My feeling is that this is only possible with svg images, is that correct or is there a way to make it work with png images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the `filter` property the following way should solve this:

```
img {
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(300%);
}
```

Comment: This works okay, but is there any way for me to select a specific blue hue? The colour needs to be as close to #79a5b9 as possible

Comment: I would suggest playing around with the three values to get as close as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS filte: grayscale(1) on any image.

Example:

```css
img {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font: .85rem sans-serif
}

img {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  object-fit: contain;
  transition: filter 300ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/36/37/273637378528968325350954c0276439.png" />
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/logo-ferrari-car-color-vector-format-aviable-ai-logo-ferrari-124870830.jpg" />
<img src="https://www.computerome.dk/download/attachments/704675874/stack.png?version=1&modificationDate=1618915111145&api=v2" />
<p>Hover to remove filter</p>
```

Comment: this doesn't add the blue hue

Comment: Ah I missed that part in that case you need a transparent image (or the white will get bluish too) - I see you provided an example

Comment: If you want to use a hex color to create the filter value here is a tool that might help 
https://isotropic.co/tool/hex-color-to-css-filter/

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing the contrast (if needed) of a grayscaled png and then use mix-blend-mode on the img's container background color.

The snippet below gives this result on the Stackoverflow logo:

[image]

```css
.container {
  background: #79a5b9;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  filter: grayscale(1) contrast(2);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDi0P.png">
</div>
```